# Is っ used with all consonants or only some of them?

Tags: gemination

I need to make simple romaji to hiragana conversion for a word based game. When implementing long consonants, I ran into a potential problem of ambiguous conversion. My question is, **is っ used with all consonants (`kgsztdcnhbpmr`) or could it be that some combinations are never actually used?**

Comment: Depending on what you're using it for, it may be more convenient for some users if double-consonant always generates a っ regardless of the consonant and actual usage in Japanese.  Sometimes double-tapping any consonant and then deleting the actual consonant can be a convenient way to generate a lone っ, and many IMEs work this way as well (so you get better consistency).  Tangentially, you also might eventually have to worry about other oddities like "d e l i"->でぃ (the "l" in the sequence stands for "little") which is useful for some katakana words (eg "Diego" = ディエゴ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe I missed it, but those are actually listed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokuon). So according to Wikipedia っ cannot be used with:

- n
- m
- r
- w
- y

Even if there are cases where っ appears in front of those consonants, those are likely irrelevant to my romaji to hiragana conversion.

Comment: You might want to process _rr_ because there are an unignorable amount of words from Latin or Italian https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AB%E3%82%AD%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B9%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AB%E3%83%8D%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B9%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%83%83%E3%83%A9

Comment: @broccoliforest How is it pronounced?

Comment: @Nothingatall usually sounds like [[ʔl͡l]] because flap variants [[ɾ]] and [[ɺ]] aren't continuant.

Comment: You may wish to implement the unexpected character combinations that can occur in Microsoft Japanese IME.  Please see Tips 5 though 8 in the following link:
http://nihonshock.com/2010/04/12-japanese-ime-tips/

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note to the above answer: while the double consonant mark (っ) is not used with "m" or "n" sounds, those sounds still exist. The ん character is simply used in its place.

Example: こんにちは, (konnichiwa)